# Yocto 2.4.2 cannot do_rootfs because of dependent package

Tags: yocto

I am working with Yocto 2.4.2 (rocko), Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Linux kernel LTSI 4.4, arm cortexA15. There are many issues while building core-image-weston. One of them is:

```
ERROR: core-image-weston-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/iwg20m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/opkg --volatile-cache -f /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/iwg20m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -t /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/iwg20m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp/ -o /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/iwg20m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/rootfs  --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version install 

libkms1

run-postinsts

gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-video4linux2

weston

opkg

psplash

libclutter-1.0-examples

alsa-tools

gtk+3-demo

gles-user-module

packagegroup-core-boot

libdrm-tests

kernel-module-gles

alsa-utils

weston-init

packagegroup-base-extended

bash

packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear' 

returned 2:

Collected errors:

 * Solver encountered 2 problem(s):

 * Problem 1/2:

    - nothing provides libgbm >= 1.0 needed by weston-2.0.0-r0.cortexa15hf-neon



 * Solution 1:

    - do not ask to install a package providing weston



 * Problem 2/2:

    - nothing provides libgbm >= 1.0 needed by weston-2.0.0-r0.cortexa15hf-neon



 * Solution 1:

    - do not ask to install a package providing weston-init



ERROR: core-image-weston-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/tmp/work/iwg20m-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-weston/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.20697

ERROR: Task (/home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3411 tasks of which 3410 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.



Summary: 1 task failed:

  /home/server-build/RZG_YoctoProject/build/../poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb:do_rootfs
```

The packages weston and weston-init require libgbm >= 1.0. In our current system, libgbm.bb was already existent. And, I can build libgbm succesfully.

```
SUMMARY = "gbm library"
LICENSE = "MIT"
SECTION = "libs"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://gbm.c;beginline=4;endline=22;md5=5cdaac262c876e98e47771f11c7036b5"

SRCREV = "84984e873a134ee67b4c99859f052bb42834245c"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/thayama/libgbm;protocol=git;branch=master"

PV = "1.0"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS = "wayland-kms udev"

inherit autotools pkgconfig

PACKAGES = " \
    ${PN} \
    ${PN}-dev \
    ${PN}-dbg \
    ${PN}-staticdev \
"

FILES_${PN} = " \
    ${libdir}/libgbm.so.* \
    ${libdir}/gbm/libgbm_kms.so.* \
    ${libdir}/gbm/*.so \
    ${libdir}/*.so \
"

PROVIDES += "gbm"

FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/gbm/*.la"
FILES_${PN}-dbg += "${libdir}/gbm/.debug/*"
FILES_${PN}-staticdev += "${libdir}/gbm/*.a"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so"
```

But the error happened. Could you help ? Thanks!

Comment: which part don't you understand? did you try suggested solutions?

Comment: Add this line to local.conf.  
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " libgbm"